# Prove $A \bigtriangleup B = B \bigtriangleup A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I`m trying to prove the following statement:
$$A \bigtriangleup B = B \bigtriangleup A$$
I know that:
$$A \bigtriangleup B = (A \cup B )\setminus (A \cap B )= (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$$
I can do that with truth table. but want to prove it by formal way.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to prove it in a formal way, what definition of $A \Delta B$ have you? Both of $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ and $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$ are common definitions.

Comment: @Ofir Attia:do you understand my answer?

Comment: No sorry, I read it few times. any way I will show it to my lecturer and ask him to explain that. thanks!

Comment: @Ofir Attia:anyway characteristic function method is easy way to show these kind of equality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if you're allowed to use the fact that the union and intersection operations are commutative, then we have:
$$
A \bigtriangleup B = (A \cup B )\setminus (A \cap B )=(B \cup A )\setminus (B \cap A )= B \bigtriangleup A
$$

Comment: well, there is another option without the fact that union and intersection operations are commutative?, its ok by me, but I just want to know more.

Comment: You only need the commutativity of the union if you use the second definition, $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 4):

In a formal way $A\Delta B$ is the set of elements belong to $A$ or $B$ but not both so these elements belong to $B$ or $A$ but not both so it's $B\Delta A$.

Answer (score 1):

proofs by characteristic function :

for any $A \subset X$ define $1_A : X \to \{ 0,1\}$ by

$$1_A(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
1 & \mbox{if } x \in A \\
0 & \mbox{if } x \notin A \\
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}\right.$$
then we have

- $\color{green}{A= B \Leftrightarrow 1_A = 1_B}$
- $1_{A \cap B}=1_A \cdot 1_B$
- $1_{A \cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_A \cdot 1_B$
- $1_{A \backslash B}= 1_A-1_A1_B$
- $\color{green}{1_{A \Delta B}=1_A+1_B-2\cdot 1_A \cdot 1_B=(1_A-1_B)^2}$

$\color{red}{Proof}$

> $$1_{A \Delta B}=1_A+1_B-2\cdot 1_A \cdot 1_B=(1_A-1_B)^2$$ and
> $$1_{B \Delta A}=1_B+1_A-2\cdot 1_B \cdot 1_A=(1_B-1_A)^2$$ then clearly we have 
> $$(1_A-1_B)^2=(1_B-1_A)^2 \to 1_{A \Delta B}=1_{B \Delta A}\iff A \bigtriangleup B = B \bigtriangleup A$$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest proof I know requires the use of one of a family of basic logic laws which are well known to students using the Gries-Schneider book or familiar with the work of Dijkstra et al., but apparently not so well known otherwise.

One simple definition of $\;\bigtriangleup\;$ is that for any $\;x\;$,
$$
x \in A \bigtriangleup B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$

And since $\;\not\equiv\;$ is symmetric, the proof is trivial: for any $\;x\;$
\begin{align}
& x \in A \bigtriangleup B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\textrm{"definition of $\;\bigtriangleup\;$"} \\
& x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\textrm{"$\;\not\equiv\;$ is symmetric"} \\
& x \in B \not\equiv x \in A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\textrm{"definition of $\;\bigtriangleup\;$"} \\
& x \in B \bigtriangleup A \\
\end{align}
Using set extensionality (two sets are equal iff they have the same elements) completes the proof.